# `split` not working with self-defined command

Tags: macros, amsmath

I have defined a handy little macro to typeset matrix elements in braket-notation and now want to align the next line to a part of this matrix element, because the 
equations are really long and aligning to the equal sign would be a colossal waste of space. However, simply putting the `&` inside the arguments of my macro gives me:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> u_1u_2u_3L&
                  P
l.21  \end{split}
```

So, I was wondering, is there a way to define the macro in a better way that allows to do this, or is it simply not possible and I have to work with `\hspace{-10ex}` or something.

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\matrixel}[3]{\left< #1\vphantom{#2#3}\right| #2\left| #3\vphantom{#1#2}\right>}

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
   \matrixel{u_1u_2u_3L}{&P}{u_1'u_2'u_3'L'} = (a +b)\\
   &\times (c+d)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note: I'm a bit confused about the terminology. Is this really a "macro" I defined here? Feel free to edit if there's a better word.

Comment: where do the `&lt;` and `&gt;` come from?  (they're not in the macro as you wrote it.) have you fed something through a web site and which has translated "`<`" to "`&lt;`" ?  or are you using an html editor which thinks it knows better than you?

Comment: You can't have a `&` inside a `\vphantom`

Comment: @wasteofspace No, the `&lt;` is what kile gives me as output. So, I have no idea where they come from (or what they mean).

Comment: @fifaltra The output should be `<argument>`, as in my fix. I'm not using Kile, so I can't say.

Comment: @egreg Hm, then that's a kile bug, it also gives me `LaTeX2e &lt;2009/09/24&gt;` right at the beginning of the output. Anyway, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @fifaltra Apparenly, the filter from TeX terminal output to the display window fears that `<` and `>` are interpreted as start and end of HTML tags, so it translates them to the corresponding HTML entities. Which is absurd, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a `&` inside a `\vphantom`, this will confuse the alignment process and produce many errors. Here's a workaround: for this particular case you use a macro `\alignmentpoint` (choose a different name, if you wish), which is made into a noop inside a special form of `\vphantom`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\matrixel}[3]{\left< #1\mvph{#2#3}\right| #2\left| #3\mvph{#1#2}\right>}
\newcommand{\alignmentpoint}{&}
\newcommand{\mvph}[1]{\vphantom{\def\alignmentpoint{}#1}}


\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
   \matrixel{u_1u_2u_3L}{\alignmentpoint P}{u_1'u_2'u_3'L'} = (a +b)\\
   &\times (c+d)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When `\matrixel` is not used in an alignment, the setting will make no harm.

[image]

Comment: so just for optimal educational value, to see if I understood this right: the `\def` redefines the `\alignmentpoint` to an empty string inside `\vphantom`?

Comment: @Mico, I agree, but aren't scaled `<` the same as scaled `\langle`?

Comment: @daleif surely so; but the real question is where the "&" came from, given that it doesn't appear in his mwe.  telling him he shouldn't have an "&" when he didn't put one there is surely confusing.  my guess is it's a kile issue.  (i've never used kile ... having learned emacs in the 80s, i'm too old to change ;-)

Comment: @wasteofspace, I think Mico deleted the comment I was refering to.

Comment: @wasteofspace yes it's a kile issue, and I think we should clean up the comments now, because our discussion will just confuse everyone now that it's edited out.