# Problem with using Split inside math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, equations, split

Below code is working fine.

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{split}
    (U\ket{v},U\ket{w}) & = (\ket{v},\ket{w}) \\
    || \ket{Uv} || & = || \ket{v} ||
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

But if I define equation environment in macros, then it is giving error that "Split can't work in math mode".

In preamble,

```
\newcommand{\benn}{\begin{equation*}}
\newcommand{\eenn}{\end{equation*}}
```

Using it inside,

```
\benn
\begin{split}
        (U\ket{v},U\ket{w}) & = (\ket{v},\ket{w}) \\
        || \ket{Uv} || & = || \ket{v} ||
\end{split}
\eenn
```

Edit:
Minimal not working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{braket}



\newcommand{\beann}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\eeann}{\end{eqnarray*}}

\begin{document}

    \beann
        \begin{split}
            (U\ket{v},U\ket{w}) & = (\ket{v},\ket{w}) \\
            || \ket{Uv} || & = || \ket{v} ||
        \end{split}
    \eeann
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE: can you see this link please? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155165/split-not-working-with-self-defined-command

Comment: Ohh sorry, I was not able to find it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry. Almost two years ago, I was unable to find it myself. :-)

Comment: I can't completely agree with @Sebastiano's link. That seems to be a different problem (hidden `&`). As a matter of fact, the code you posted works perfectly fine for me. I have suspects about what you are doing wrong, but you should post a a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue,  starting with  `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @campa Mine was just an indication. Not a duplicate at all, I would never have done it for a new user. I simply thought that an old question could make him think.

Comment: @campa I have added minimal example, can you try that?

Comment: Your MWE works for me.

Comment: I am using share latex. It is not giving error in "logs and output files" but in writing area it is showing error mark.

Comment: The code given by the op also compiles/displays fine for me. However, there is the line in the log file `Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use 'split' here;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with 'aligned' on input line 25.` (Which I agree with: your use case really seems better treated by either `gather` or `align` or `aligned`, since the two displayed lines are two distinct equations, not one long equation split on multiple lines.) Can you post a screen cap of what you see on ShareLateX and also post the log file?

Comment: Also, why are you using `eqnarray` when using amsmath? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align If I replace your `eqnarray*` in the definition of `beann` with `equation*`, the `amsmath warning` in my previous comment goes away and everything still displays fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note: in the future please give a MWE and the *exact* error/warning. In your question you say the compiler

> is giving error that "Split can't work in math mode".

while running the code gives the *warning*

```
Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use `split' here;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned' on input line 19.
```

For people trying to figure out what is going on there is quite a difference `:-)`

Now to the issue: the `amsmath` user's guide states

> The `split` environment is designed to serve as the entire body of an equation, or an entire line of an `align` or `gather` environment. There cannot be any printed material before or after it within the same enclosing structure.

But `eqnarray` (which shouldn't be used anyway when `amsmath` is loaded, see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/82917)) kind of does that, so that's why this is failing.

In this particular case, I see no reason to enclose `split` within an environment providing aligning points. You can use `align*` (without `split`), or `\[ ... \]`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\Vert}{\Vert}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

Either
\begin{align*}
(U\ket{v},U\ket{w}) & = (\ket{v},\ket{w}) \\
\norm{\ket{Uv}} & = \norm{\ket{v}}
\end{align*}
or
\[
\begin{split}
(U\ket{v},U\ket{w}) & = (\ket{v},\ket{w}) \\
\norm{\ket{Uv}} & = \norm{\ket{v}}
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

- I removed a couple of packages irrelevant for the MWE
- I loaded `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`) and defined a macro `\norm`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. What is `\[ ... \]` ? Does it denote math mode?

Comment: Once you load `amsmath` it's the same as `equation*`.